# HiveQL UNION ALL

Tags: hadoop, union, hive, hiveql

I have table_A:

```
id var1 var2
1   a    b
2   c    d
```

Table_B:

```
id var1 var2  
3   e    f
4   g    h
```

All I want is table, combined:

```
id var1 var2
1   a    b
2   c    d
3   e    f
4   g    h
```

This is my .hql:

```
CREATE TABLE combined AS
SELECT all.id, all.var1, all.var2
FROM (
  SELECT a.id, a.var1, a.var2  
  FROM table_A a  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT b.id, b.var1, b.var2  
  FROM table_B b
) all;
```

I'm coding straight from page 112 of Programming Hive by Edward Capriolo, et al.

The error I get, no matter what ostensibly reasonable variation of the above that I try, is

> `cannot recognize input near '.' 'id' ',' in select expression.`

I have tried using `AS` between the table name and the alias, asterisks since I want everything from both tables. Same error. I've tried other things and gotten other errors... All I want to do is `UNION` two tables. (I've tried `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` — same error).

Answer (score 15):

Just replace all with another word. It seems to be a reserved keyword. E.g:

```
CREATE TABLE combined AS
SELECT unioned.id, unioned.var1, unioned.var2
FROM (
  SELECT a.id, a.var1, a.var2  
  FROM table_A a  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT b.id, b.var1, b.var2  
  from table_B b
) unioned;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have similar query working. Just changing table name and column names. Try this. Hope this helps you.

```
create table new_table as
select
distinct
id, name
FROM
table1
union all
select
distinct
id,name
from
table2 
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
CREATE TABLE combined AS
SELECT id, var1, var2
FROM (
  SELECT id, var1, var2  
  FROM table_A
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT id, var1, var2  
  from table_B
) a;
```