# Combine many tables in Hive using UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to append one variable from several tables together (aka row-bind, concatenate) to make one longer table with a single column in Hive.  I think this is possible using `UNION ALL` based on this question ( [HiveQL UNION ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096968/hiveql-union-all) ), but I'm not sure an efficient way to accomplish this?

The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_combined AS
SELECT b.var1 FROM tmp_table1 b
UNION ALL
SELECT c.var1 FROM tmp_table2 c
UNION ALL
SELECT d.var1 FROM tmp_table3 d
UNION ALL
SELECT e.var1 FROM tmp_table4 e
UNION ALL
SELECT f.var1 FROM tmp_table5 f
UNION ALL
SELECT g.var1 FROM tmp_table6 g
UNION ALL
SELECT h.var1 FROM tmp_table7 h;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try with following coding...

```
Select * into tmp_combined  from 
(
    SELECT b.var1 FROM tmp_table1 b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.var1 FROM tmp_table2 c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.var1 FROM tmp_table3 d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.var1 FROM tmp_table4 e
    UNION ALL
    SELECT f.var1 FROM tmp_table5 f
    UNION ALL
    SELECT g.var1 FROM tmp_table6 g
    UNION ALL
    SELECT h.var1 FROM tmp_table7 h
) CombinedTable
```

Use with the statement :
set hive.exec.parallel=true

This will execute different selects simultaneously otherwise it would be step by step.

Comment: Does this write into new table?

Comment: Yes, its do create a new table..

Answer (score 4):

I would say that's both straightforward and efficient way to do the row-bind, at least, that's what I would use in my code.
Btw, it might cause you some syntax error if you put your pseudo code directly, you may try:

```sql
create table join_table as
select * from
(select ...
join all
select
join all
select...) tmp;
```

Comment: what dose tmp means ?

Answer (score 3):

I did same concept but for different tables `employee` and `location` that might help you I believe :

```
DATA:Table_e-employee
empid empname
13  Josan
8   Alex
3   Ram
17  Babu
25  John

Table_l-location
empid emplocation
13  San Jose
8   Los Angeles
3   Pune,IN
17  Chennai,IN
39  Banglore,IN

hive> SELECT e.empid AS a ,e.empname AS b FROM employee e 
UNION ALL 
SELECT l.empid AS a,l.emplocation AS b FROM location l;
```

OutPut with alias `a` and  `b`:

```
13  San Jose
8   Los Angeles
3   Pune,IN
17  Chennai,IN
39  Banglore,IN
13  Josan
8   Alex
3   Ram
17  Babu
25  John
```